# Lion/other browsers than Safari: Are there QuickLook-plug-ins?

Tags: safari, quicklook-plugin

We all like Safari don't we? :-)

But in case anyone would prefer to use Firefox/Opera/other browsers, is there a way to view files with QuickLook, perhaps via a plugin, or some other method?

Any ideas or links for these?
Are they difficult to develop?

Comment: What do you mean by *their files*?

Comment: Are you talking about HTML files on your filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

To develop Quick Look plugins, you can visit [this site](http://www.qlplugins.com/about), which states:

> **About QLPlugins.com**
>
> QLPlugins.com is a repository for Quick Look Plugins, which are
>   available starting with Mac OS X 10.5. In addition, I seek to provide
>   information for developers seeking to create QuickLook Plugins and to
>   power users looking to use QuickLook more effectively. If you have
>   developed a QuickLook Plugin and would like for it to appear on this
>   website or are aware of any QuickLook Plugins I have missed, send an
>   e-mail to feedback@qlplugins.com and I will include it.
>
> **About QuickLook & QuickLook Plugins**
>
> QuickLook was introduced by Apple in starting with OS X 10.5
>   (Leopard). By selecting a file in the Finder and pressing the
>   space-bar, a preview of the file pops up. QuickLook Plugins, or
>   QuickLook Generators, are files ending in .qlgenerator and are used to
>   generate these previews. These plugins are also responsible for
>   generating the previews in CoverFlow mode in the Finder.
>
> While many file formats are supported out of the box, some common and
>   many obscure formats are not. Fortunately, Apple's programmers made it
>   easy for developers to create their own custom QuickLook Plugins. This
>   site seeks to serve as a repository linking to these Plugins and as a
>   resource for developers looking for information on developing their
>   own QuickLook Plugins.

The [Quick Look developer page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) was also linked in this [Apple discussion forum post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2284464?start=0&tstart=0).